# AndEngine Examples not working

Tags: android, andengine

I configured the AndEngine example on my eclipse a day ago by following a video tutorial. It was running fine. But the very next day, when I tried to run the example, it says your project contains errors. I check the properties of project and other things but found nothing like error. I am unable to figure out what is causing the project to build. Can anyone help me in this regard?

I can't see any error. I just show a cross on Examples project. I deleted all the extensions and examples and redownloaded but error stayed there. Here is the screenshot of eclipse.
[image]

Sometimes, when I delete some other project, it gives the following error message:

```
An internal error occurred during Re-indexing repository AndEngine Empty path not permitted.
```

Comment: pls post your error messages and add more details abt the problem

Comment: have you tried restarting eclipse and then cleaning-building project again? also check for the configuration settings if you import any library or jar files.

Comment: yes I restarted eclipse even I redownloaded the entire andengine extantions as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I got rid of problem. Actually my debug certificate was expired. That's why it was not building the project. I deleted the Debug.keystore file from .android folder to regenerate the keystore.