# Where to find a sample code for game like tetris for AndEngine in android?

Tags: android, andengine

I am doing a game based on a tetris using AndEngine but i did not get any any sample code to start this game. So if there is any tetris game sample, so that i can study it and modify that code according to my game. So if any one know there is source code for this in AndEngine please do reply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't many games in AndEngine that are open source. You can, however, take a look at the AndEngine examples that show you how to use the features of the engine. Check them out from https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples

Answer (score 1):

Ask the people that made AndEngine ? Relate to this guy..

[AndEngine Examples not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763518/andengine-examples-not-working)